# Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence of the series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence of the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^n x^{n^4}$

I'm really lost as to how to approach this problem. The other power-series problems were all very straight-forward compared to this one.

I attempted it using both ratio test and root test. I managed to get further with the root test and ended up with 
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|n x^{n^3}|$. How would you take the limit of $x^{n^3}$?

Comment: Rewriting $n\lvert x\rvert^{n^3}=e^{n^3\ln \lvert x\rvert + \ln n}$ may help to see the behavior. This converges (to a real value) iff the exponent converges to either $-\infty$ or a constant.